# Vuetify and require.js: How do I show a dynamic component?

Tags: vue.js, requirejs, vuetify.js

I am creating a tab component that loads its `v-tab-item` components dynamically, given an array of configuration objects that consist of `tabName`, `id`, and `tabContent` which is a resource location for the component. I have it successfully loading the components. However, they don't actually initialize (or run their `created()` methods) until I switch tabs. I just get empty tabs with the correct labels. Using the DOM inspector initially shows just `<componentId></componentId>`, and then when I switch tabs, those tags are replaced with all of the component's content.

How do I get the dynamic components to initialize as soon as they are loaded?

EDIT: I created a CodePen here:

https://codepen.io/sgarfio/project/editor/DKgQON

But as this is my first CodePen, I haven't yet figured out how to reference other files in the project (i.e. what to set tabContent to so that require.js can load them up). I'm seeing "Access is denied" in the console, which makes it sound like it found the files but isn't allowed to access them, which is weird because all the files belong to the same project. So my CodePen doesn't even work as well as my actual project. But maybe it will help someone understand what I'm trying to do.

Also, after poking around a bit more, I found this:

http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

that says I should change the key on the component and that will force the component to re-render. I also found this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Which has a pretty good example of what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't force the async component to *initialize* in the first place. That's what I need the async components to do - they don't initialize until I switch tabs. In fact they don't even show up in the network calls. Vue is simply generating a placeholder for them.

Comment: Have you tried moving the functions from `created:` into `mounted:` ? ...Also, not sure if it has anything to do with it, but there appears to be a typo here:  `for(var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; ++i) { this.loadComponent(this.tabs[i]; }`  ...it should be: `this.loadComponent(this.tabs[i]);`

Comment: I don't have anything in `created`... Do you mean `updated`? I have tried putting that code in all the lifecycle hooks. I'm actually loading the tab configuration from a service (not shown here) so I found that it only gets called after the configuration is loaded if I put it in `updated`. Also good call on the typo, that's not in my actual code, I wanted to make a minimal example and just typed it in wrong. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I was referring to the lifecycle hooks. I thought you meant the 'created' lifecycle hook.. my b! I think if you supplied some psuedo code using codepen.io or something like it, that reproduces your issue, folks would be able to assist you better/more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put together a CodePen, but couldn't get it to run. Could be the firewall I'm behind at work not letting me get the Vuetify libraries. I might try again from home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working! What I ended up doing was to emit an event from the code that loads the async components to indicate that that component was loaded. The listener for that event keeps a count of how many components have been loaded (it already knows how many there should be), and as soon as it receives the right number of these events, it changes the value of `this.active` (`v-model` value for the `v-tabs` component, which indicates which tab is currently active) to "0". I tried this because as I noted before, the async components were loading/rendering whenever I switched tabs. I also have prev/next buttons to set `this.active`, and today I noticed that if I used the "next" button instead of clicking on a tab, it would load the async components but not advance the tab. I had already figured out how to emit an event from the loading code, so all I had to do at that point was capture the number of loaded components and then manipulate `this.active`.

I might try to update my CodePen to reflect this, and if I do I'll come back and comment accordingly. For now, here's a sample of what I ended up with. I'm still adding things to make it more robust (e.g. in case the configuration object contains a non-existent component URL), but this is the basic gist of it.

```
created: function() {
  this.$on("componentLoaded", () => {
    this.numTabsInitialized++;
    if(this.numTabsInitialized == this.numTabs) {
      // All tabs loaded; update active to force them to load
      this.active = "0";
    }
  })
},
methods: {
  loadComponent: function(config) {
    var id = config.id;
    var compPath = config.tabContent;
    var self = this;
    require([compPath], function(comp) {
      Vue.component(id, comp);
      self.$emit("componentLoaded");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: your codePen doesn't seem to be working, could you update to get it working? I'm attempting to do something similar with using requirejs to load vue components dynamically. thanks.

Comment: @user:2359306 - fixed. Hope it helps!